# Hiragino Sans W8 font shows on storyboard and simulator, but not on device

Tags: ios, xcode, uifont

I want to use the Hiragino Sans W8 font inside my project in Xcode 11.

I selected the font from the interface builder like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6UVy.png). The font shows in the storyboard and simulator on any device with iOS 13, but it does not show on my device running iOS 13.1. I find this weird because this font is originally in Xcode, its not a font that I imported. I tried selecting the font from attributed text, but this did not work either.

Is this font not available for use on actual devices?

Comment: You can find some articles on "available fonts ios". And I cannot find `Hiragino Sans W8` in any of the available lists.

Comment: @OOPer  I checked the System Fonts on Apple Developer (https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/), and the font is placed in the "Downloadable Fonts" category for iOS. Do you have any idea what this means and how to download?

Comment: I cannot find any articles on how to download such fonts till now. You can export  Hiragino Sans W8 using Font Book of your Mac and embed into your app, but I do not know it's legal nor appropriate for iOS.

Comment: @OOPer Have you find how to download "Downloadable Fonts"?

Comment: @helloyako, no, using Font Book app is the only way I know. I have not tried yet, but your app might be able to [download fonts on demand](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/DownloadFont/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: @OOPer Cool! Thank you for link. I'll try that.